# Sharing container ip and port across the hosts

Tags: networking, docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

We have a set of docker containers spread across the several hosts. Some containers are part of the same logical group, i.e. *network* so containers should be able to talk directly, accessing each other IP and Port (which is randomized by docker).

The situation is similar to when you use *networks* in Docker 1.10 and docker-compose 1.6x on one host, but spread on many hosts.

I know swarm with etcd/zookeeper can manage and connect the cluster of dockers, but I don't know how my app in one container would know about the IP address and port of the other part in other container on the other host.

Comment: How do containers actually discover IP and ports? It seems like you may need to set a service discovery solution.

Comment: It looks so @Auzias... Wondering how Docker can help me here.

Comment: Not that I am aware of, and I really doubt that. You'll have to either use a discovery service (such as zookeeper, consul or etcd) or implement one on by yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app doesn't need to know the IP address of the container. You can use the service name or some other alias as the hostname. The embedded DNS server will resolve it to the correct IP address.

With this setup you don't need host ports at all, so you'll already know the port because it's a static value.

Comment: You are talking about docker overlay networks? Also - i need port. On one host I might have e.g. 2 containers of the same thing, like 2 redis, so they need different ports; which Docker already provide.

Comment: No, they don't need different ports. Ports are only required to be unique **per interface** not per host. Each container has it's own interface, so with overlay networking you don't have to expose anything to the host, and you can use a predefined port.

Comment: Yes, it does require the use of overlay networks if you're using multi-host. On a single host you can use the bridge network, and it will work the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Multi-host networking for Docker is covered in this tutorial: https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/get-started-overlay/

Comment: This does not offer a solution to the last part of the question "I don't know how my app in one container would know about the IP address and port of the other part in other container on the other host.".

Comment: Exactly. I don't see how to get the IPs and ports.

Comment: The page clearly says there are four conditions in order for the multi-host network to work. So you will have to have a discovery backend such as Consul.